# How to change oh-my-zsh's global completion behaviour?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Today, I tried *zsh*. And I encountered a serious user-experience issue with a simple action.

[image]

When I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete my command here, in *bash* I'll smoothly get `sh auto_rsync.sh`.
But in *zsh*, with *oh-my-zsh* installed, I got a bunch of suggestions which aren't what I need.
How could I disable this *global autocomplete tendency* of *oh-my-zsh* and let it doing autocomplete at current context?

Comment: How is this a Zsh issue? You probably don't realize that `sh` can take any file on your `PATH`? It's Bash being primitive and can't complete to the full selection. Anyway, you can always customize your completer to whatever you want. Read `man zshcompsys`.

Comment: @4ae1e1, actually it's an `oh-my-zsh` issue, when I use the original zsh, it behave the same as bash.

Comment: since completions are [not documented in oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins) (each provide its own) and I can only guess which completer you're getting, it may be best to specify that you want a file path completion: `sh ./au` and hit TAB